# Lutris wont Uninstall

Tags: wine, uninstall, games, lutris

Ubuntu 22.04.01
Installed Lutris and it wont run Witcher3/GOG.
Lutris Installs and I can launch Witcher3 directly from Wine but when you try to run it  from Lutris it wont run. Ive installed the Package Manager version 5.9 and the flatpack
version 5.11

Ive uninstalled Lutris from Package Manager and also ran these commands
$ sudo apt remove lutris
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove lutris
$ sudo apt autoremove

But there is still a launcher for lutris in the Main Ubuntu Menu and when you click it Lutris launches.

Anybody got any idea whats going on and how to uninstall lutris? I want to try uninstalling it so that I can reinstall and see if it fixes the problem with it not launching witcher3/GOG

Cheers

--Edit --
Lutris was installed using this command given on their webpage
$ flatpak install flathub net.lutris.Lutris

this drops a deb file  (lutris_0.5.11_all.deb) in your directory and I then installed it using (In fact I may have downloaded this seperately)
$ sudo apt install ./lutris_0.5.11_all.deb

Comment: What was the exact command used to install Lutris?

Comment: It was from the Lutris webpage  $ flatpak install flathub net.lutris.Lutris and then $ sudo apt install ./lutris_0.5.11_all.deb

Comment: So to remove it you need the reverse commands. For the second install it needs to be sudo apt remove lutris_0.5.11_all.deb for the first one it needs to be flatpak remove flathub net.lutris.Lutris

Comment: Any time you install anything you will always use the reverse command to remove it.

Comment: Thanks mate. That seems to have worked. The flatpak remove command did the trick. Cheers!

Comment: Great I will make it an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you install an app make sure you note what the command was used to install it. Flatpak needs flatpak remove to remove it, snap needs snap remove to remove it and if it was installed with apt it needs apt-get remove to remove it.

So to remove it you need the reverse commands.

For the second install it needs to be sudo apt remove lutris_0.5.11_all.deb

For the first one it needs to be flatpak remove flathub net.lutris.Lutris

After running these two commands the two apps that were installed will be removed.